# UISlider not flipped on changing the app language to RTL. | iOS

Tags: ios, iphone

I have to make an app in which one UISlider is there to display distance. This app is supported in RTL language. On changing the app language to RTL app all control flipped accordingly but UISlider is not getting flipped. Is there any special configurations to flip UISlider in iOS

Comment: What version of iOS+Xcode are you using? How are you changing the app language to RTL? Through Settings?

Comment: Xcode 6.4 iOS 9.2. I changes the language from setting

Comment: Can you please try using Xcode 7.2?

Comment: This happened with me on `iOS 7.1.2`, But on `iOS 9.3` it worked fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UISlider follows same direction in both RTL and LTR mode. So this should not get flipped OS does this for us and prevents flipping UISlider control.
If some app has a specific requirement than you can check the application layout mode by

```
if(UIApplication.sharedApplication().userInterfaceLayoutDirection == UIUserInterfaceLayoutDirection.RightToLeft)
        {
                    uiSlider.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1.0, 1.0);
        }
```