# Swift: UISlider one side of track not rounded

Tags: ios, swift, uislider

I have a custom UISlider, but there is a side of the slider which is not rounded[image]

Here my custom view:

```
class PrimarySliderView: UISlider {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        setup()
    }

    override func trackRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return CGRect(origin: bounds.origin, size: CGSize(width: bounds.width, height: 6))
    }

    func setup() {
        tintColor = .cornFlowerBlue
    }
```

How to round the right side also?

**EDIT**

The slider is cutted because my application is RTL, when I change to LTR this display correctly but not in RTL, how to resolve this problem?

In My AppDelegate I force RTL:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft

        return true
    }
```

Comment: i tested your code ... it gives me perfect round corner slider

Comment: The 2 sides are rounded ??

Comment: Yes as @jawadAli said I also tested just changed ```.cornFlowerBlue``` to ```.blue``` (Because I didn't define this extension to UIColor), & It is giving round shape at both end.

Comment: Also add `@IBDesignable` at the top of class to assign it directly from storyboard.

Comment: Really strange thank you, I'll try to find out where the problem comes from

Comment: Even if I use `@IBInspectable var trackHeight: CGFloat = 2
    
    override func trackRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return CGRect(origin: bounds.origin, size: CGSize(width: bounds.width, height: trackHeight))
    }` then also it is perfect

Comment: I understood why the slider is cutted because my application is RTL, when I change to LTR this display correctly but not in RTL, how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you need to add rounded image for minimum and maximum track
or you can create rounded view using colors

other workaround is

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
          super.layoutSubviews()

        self.layer.sublayers![1].cornerRadius = 10

    }
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understood why the slider is cutted because my application is RTL, when I change to LTR this display correctly but not in RTL, how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Yes but your solution does not resolve my problem, the cutted side round only the top corner… My application is in RTL. In LTR it works but not in RTL. And for the moment my application must be only in RTL

Comment: can you share code with me ? or you have teamviewer ?

Comment: `we.tl/t-gKxwAYcBd4` .. check it now ... and let me know

Comment: Works thanks, remove this `layer.cornerRadius = 10` from your answer

Comment: The above solution with sublayers, fails on iOS 14.

Comment: @Yoku I have added an updated solution below, check it.

Comment: This fails in iOS 15

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution/workaround and it works with iOS 14 based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54283173/8742572).
Also, it is tweaked to solve blurry edges.

```
if UIApplication.shared.userInterfaceLayoutDirection == .rightToLeft {
        setMinimumTrackImage(getImageWithColor(color: .blue, size: frame.size).resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsets(top: 3, left: 3, bottom: 3, right: 3), resizingMode: .stretch), for: .normal)
}
```

And here is the implementation of getImageWithColor:

```
private func getImageWithColor(color: UIColor, size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
    
    let layer: CALayer =  CALayer()
    layer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
    layer.masksToBounds = true
    layer.cornerRadius = 3
    layer.backgroundColor = color.cgColor
    
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
    layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
}
```

**NOTE:** Don't forget to change cornerRadius and UIEdgeInsets to suit your needs.

Before applying the fix:

[image: Before the fix]

After applying the fix:

[image: After the fix]

Comment: this solved it perfectly for me

Answer (score 1):

iOS14+ version of [Jawad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59949125/95309)

```
final class RoundedSlider: UISlider {
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
            if let layers = layer.sublayers?.first?.sublayers, layers.count > 0, let layer = layers[1] {
                layer.cornerRadius = layer.bounds.height / 2
            }
        } else {
            if let layers = layer.sublayers, layers.count > 0, let layer = layers[1] {
                layer.cornerRadius = layer.bounds.height / 2
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me, except I'm not sure if @Claus tested it in a compiler because you have to move `let layer = layers[1]` outside of the if/else condition because `layers[1]` is not "un-wrappable" since it does not produce `nil`. I also changed `layers.count > 1` (instead of 0) to ensure it never errors when accessing the`layers[1]` index.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
if(UIApplication.sharedApplication().userInterfaceLayoutDirection == UIUserInterfaceLayoutDirection.RightToLeft)
{
   uiSlider.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1.0, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understood why the slider is cutted because my application is RTL, when I change to LTR this display correctly but not in RTL, how to resolve this problem?

Comment: i Updated the answer, try that one

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem, I want to keep the RTL meaning

Comment: UISlider follows same direction in both RTL and LTR mode.

Comment: You can check this ans i hope that will helps you

Comment: No the minimumValue  and maximumValue does not have the same direction

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34798258/uislider-not-flipped-on-changing-the-app-language-to-rtl-ios/38811865#38811865 see this one

Answer (score 0):

**For SwiftUI**

The problem occurs, as mentioned in the question when forcing the environment to be RTL.
like so `.environment(\.layoutDirection, .rightToLeft)`

I found a simple solution that works for me.

Just use a rotation effect like so: `.rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 180))` on the slider and it will look as if it's RTL.

This will just rotate the slider 180 degrees

> Note

if you would like to add some padding make sure to put it after this modifier so it will make sense or else you will have to enter the opposite edge. (for example `.bottom` instead of `.top`)

**This will apply the padding to the top**

```
Slider(value: $progress)
    .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 180))
    .padding(.top, 20) // After rotating
```

**This will apply the padding to the bottom**

```
Slider(value: $progress)
    .padding(.top, 20) // before 
    .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 180))
```

Hope this helps :)